# Adding to the same string

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a variable `install = "6 "` and I need to add it, like this:

```
If CheckBox6.Checked = True Then
    install = &"6 "
Else
    If CheckBox7.Checked = True Then
        install = &"7 "
    End If
End If
```

I need the output to be `"6 7"`.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? It's very hard to tell what you want.

Comment: i want the output to be "6 7" i need install to be "6 7"

Comment: `If CheckBox6.Checked = True Then
                                install &= "6 "
                            Else
                                If CheckBox7.Checked = True Then
                                    install &= "7 "`

Comment: what output did you get?

Comment: 6 and no 7 do you need more code?

Comment: I'm making some assumptions that may not be true, but I think your issue is with your `If` / `Else` logic, not the string concatenation.  The `If CheckBox7.Checked...` block should not be in the `Else` block if you want `install` to equal "6 7 " when both checkboxes are checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need separate IF logic:

```
If CheckBox6.Checked = True Then
    install = &"6 "
End If
'Else <--- Comment else
If CheckBox7.Checked = True Then
        install = &"7 "
    End If
End If
```

So If both check boxes are checked you will get "`6 7`".

Comment: calling 'install.Trim'. Will lose the trailing space. Ie "6 7" as in you initial request.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add another string to your variable you need to use the & or + opperator, but you need to specify what you want to add and where you want to add (the new string to).

Here is an example:

```
Dim myString as String
myString = "Hello" 'You variable now holds the string "Hello"  
myString = myString & " World!" 'Your variable now holds the string "Hello World!"
MessageBox.Show(myString) 'Will show a message box with the text "Hello World!"
```

However, you also have a second problem.  Since the concatenation is being done in an `If/Else` block, only one or the other will ever get executed.  In order to execute both in succession, you need move the second concatenation out of the `Else` and put it into its own `If` block:

```
If CheckBox1.Checked Then 
    myString = myString & "Hello " 
End If 
If CheckBox2.Checked Then 
    myString = myString & "World! " 
End If 
MesssageBox.Show(myString) 'Shows the text "Hello World!" if both are checked
```

Comment: You need to change your if code. If the checkbox6 is checked then it does not check if the checkbox7 is checked.

Comment: As I said before you need to change your if.`If checkbox1.checked then 
 myString = myString & "Hello " 
End If 
If checkbox2.checked then
 myString = myString & "World! "
End If

Msgbox(myString) 'Shows the text Hello World!`

Comment: @Jared This example should be working for you. If it isn't working show how you implemented it. Just saying it doesn't work gives us nothing to help you with.

Comment: `If CheckBox6.Checked = True Then
                                install = install & "6"
                            Else
                                If CheckBox7.Checked = True Then
                                    install = install & "7"`

Comment: Dont put the second checkbox insíde the else.

Comment: @Lucas welcome to SO!  Thanks making the effort, working with Jared until you were able to grasp what his issues really were.  I'm not sure why he chose to give the credit to someone else when you were the one that helped him work through it to a resolution.  I took the liberty of expanding upon your answer by copying the details from your comments.  Feel free to edit it again if you disagree with my edits.  In the future, it's best to put longer/multi-line code snippets in your answer rather than in comments so that they are easier to read.  Hope to see you around in the future.